# Change help_text position using as_crispy_form templatetag

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-crispy-forms

I have a field which is rendered using as_crispy_field templatetag

```
{{ form.field|as_crispy_field }}
```

I want to change the help text position to be beside the label with red color

---

**This is the current output:**
[image: the current output]

**I want it to be something similar to this:**
[image: The planned output]

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the issue by **overriding crispy_forms templates.**

By looking at the structure of the crispy_forms template [crispy_forms/templates](https://github.com/django-crispy-forms/django-crispy-forms/tree/master/crispy_forms/templates), I've seen that they read the formatting from a folder *crispy_forms/templates/{{ TEMPLATE_PACK }}*
e.g. [crispy_forms/templates/bootstrap4](https://github.com/django-crispy-forms/django-crispy-forms/tree/master/crispy_forms/templates/bootstrap4)

I've decided to create my own customized folder to change the layout for that field and placed it under the project's template folder.

Adding a file to that folder, named 'field.html'; because of that how crispy will read the formatting, and changed whatever I want to customize.

---

The customized file [templates/bootstrap4/field.html](https://github.com/django-crispy-forms/django-crispy-forms/blob/master/crispy_forms/templates/bootstrap4/field.html)

The changed lines (lines 13-17 on [templates/bootstrap4/field.html](https://github.com/django-crispy-forms/django-crispy-forms/blob/master/crispy_forms/templates/bootstrap4/field.html))

```
{% if field.label and not field|is_checkbox and form_show_labels %}
        <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}" class="{% if 'form-horizontal' in form_class %}col-form-label {% endif %}{{ label_class }}{% if field.field.required %} requiredField{% endif %}">
            {{ field.label|safe }}{% if field.field.required %}<span class="asteriskField">*</span>{% endif %}
        </label>
        {% comment %} ---------- Customization starts here ---------- {% endcomment %}
        &nbsp; &nbsp;<strong style="color: red; font-size:14px">
                            <i>{{field.help_text|safe}}</i>
        </strong>
        {% comment %} ---------- Customization ends here ---------- {% endcomment %}
    {% endif %}
```

Field Error handling (lines 41-44 on [templates/bootstrap4/field.html](https://github.com/django-crispy-forms/django-crispy-forms/blob/master/crispy_forms/templates/bootstrap4/field.html))

```
    <div class="{{ field_class }}">
        {% crispy_field field %}
        {% comment %} ---------- Error handling starts here ---------- {% endcomment %}
    {% if error_text_inline %}
        {% include 'bootstrap4/layout/field_errors.html' %}
    {% else %}
        {% include 'bootstrap4/layout/field_errors_block.html' %}
    {% endif %}
        {% comment %} ---------- Error handling ends here ---------- {% endcomment %}
    </div>
```

And modified the field in the template to read from the new folder

```
{{ form.myField|as_crispy_field:"custom_crispy_folder" }}
```